# Search for public facebook pages / workaround?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Currently there does not seem to be an official way to search for public pages via API. We found out that we can search for places (e.g. search?type=place&q=company_name) but this only includes pages that are stored as a place.

Is there any third party API or other solution, how to get the same results like from https://www.facebook.com/search/pages/?q=company_name

With this URL the problem is that it requires a valid Facebook login. I want to avoid to create fake users and login via cURL and parse the results. This is really bad and risky.

This would really help ... we googled hours and did not find anything!

Comment: What is the purpose of this? Usually, you’d just use your app user’s user access token for any such searches.

Comment: This is possible to search via API by using the access token of the user?! if yes ... this would be the perfect solution. Which endpoint do i need to use?

Comment: basically the purpose is: our user can schedule and publish a facebook post via our app. we also want to support the @ mention feature, like facebook offers it directly. I know its not possible to mention a user, but a page should be possible.

Comment: Despite calling it “pages search”, they only offer search for places that have a page attached, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/searching/

Comment: yes i know about this. But other publishing tools like buffer.com return more results this endpoint provides. They return the same results like when searching inside facebook. I dont know how they can do it, beside parsing facebook search results with a simulate logged in user.

Comment: Could be scraping, could be using their own data (if they have a large enough user base), could have a special deal with Facebook that provides them access to some APIs normal 3rd-party apps don’t get …

Comment: even a small competitor of us returns same results ... they dont have many users. so there need to be a way. scraping facebook with fake users is not the best idea i think. how about rating limit? if we just use one fake user, add some proxies and perform the searches with this user by setting the cookie inside each cURL request.

Comment: Scraping without prior explicit permission by Facebook will likely get you in trouble sooner or later.

Comment: right, thats why i want to avoid. so even there is another direct way or there is a third party that can offer this data via API. but i were not able to find both ... after hours of researching.

Comment: @ForeverGolf Did you ever find a solution for this? I am stuck in the same problem now

Comment: @Alaa_kamal its working with https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/searching/?locale=de_DE but you need to send your app to review to get the required scope